# Prove that the square of any odd number is equal to a multiple of $8$ plus $1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, congruence-relations

Given the following problem:

> Prove that the square any odd number is equal to a multiple of $8$ plus $1$:
>
> 1. Using congruence.
> 2. Applying the division algorithm.

I believe that the square of an odd number would be represented by $(2k_1-1)^2$ and based on the problem, it appears to be stating that; $(8k_2+1)$ divides $(2k_1-1)^2$.

Therefore, for the first part of the problem (**1.**), would it be $(2k_1-1)^2\equiv0\mod{(8k_2+1)}$?

If not how can I interpret and solve this problem including the second part?

Comment: what is the meaning of "the square all odd numbers"?

Comment: When you know modular arithmetic well (and I guess that is item 1.), you only need to check $(\pm 1)^2$ and $(\pm 3)^2$ modulo $8$.

Comment: @uniquesolution $x^2 : x \in \{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, ...\}$?

Comment: I think that should have beeb "the square of **any** odd number".  Yes, any odd number can be written in the form $2k_1- 1$ for some integer $k_1$ so "the square of any odd number is $(2k_1- 1)^2= 4k_1^2- 4k_1+ 1= 4(k_1^2- k_1$.  Now, if you can prove that $k_1^2- k_1$ is always **even** you are done!

Comment: The question says "multiple of 8 plus 1", which does not mean it's divisible by (8k + 1). It means it's divisible by 8, with a remainder of 1.

Comment: $\left(2n + 1\right)^{2} = 4n\left(n + 1\right) + 1$ and $n\left(n + 1\right)$ is $\color{red}{\large even}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $k$ be a non-negative integer. Then $$(2k+1)^2=4k^2+4k+1=4k(k+1)+1.$$ The product of two consecutive integers must be even so let $k(k+1)=2n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $$(2k+1)^2=4(2n)+1=8n+1\equiv1 \mod8$$ as desired.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a very easy way, which should be better known:

Every odd number is of the form $4n\pm 1$ and $$(4n\pm 1)^2=16n^2\pm 8n +1$$

---

Here is another way just for the record. The squares of consecutive odd numbers differ by a multiple of $8$ because $$(2n+1)^2-(2n-1)^2=8n$$ Since $1^2=1$ leaves remainder $1$ when divided by $8$, this is true for any odd number.

Note also that you can write $(2n+1)^2=8T_n+1$ where $T_n$ is the $n^{th}$ triangular number. There is a neat dissection of an odd square into triangles plus the central square which gives a visual demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

$$(2n+1)^2 =4n^2+4n+1=4n(n+1)+1.$$ Notice that one of $n$ or $n+1$ is even, so $n(n+1)$ is always  even. That makes $4n(n+1)$ a multiple of 8.Thus  $(2n+1)^2=8k+1$ That is $(2n+1)^2\equiv 1$   mod(8).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that any odd number can be represented as $2k_{1}-1$ for some integer $k$. You want to interpret the problem as saying that
$$(2k-1)^{2} = 8k_{2} +1$$
for some integer $k_{2}$, or
$$(2k-1)^{2} \equiv 1 \bmod{8}$$
(not that it is divisible by $8k_{2}+1$). Another way of saying this is that when you divide $(2k-1)^{2}$ by $8$, you have a remainder of $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Use induction to show $(2n+1)^2 \equiv 1 \mod 8$.

When $n=0$, $1 \equiv 1 \mod 8$.

Assuming it is true for $n=k$, we'll prove for $n=k+1$:
$$(2(k+1)+1)^2=((2k+1)+2)^2=(2k+1)^2+4(2k+1)+4=(2k+1)^2+8(k+1) \equiv (2k+1)^2 \equiv 1 \mod 8.$$

Answer (score 1):

The usual proof for such a congruence questions goes like this:

If $n$ is odd, then $n \equiv 1,3,5,7 \bmod 8$.

If $n \equiv 1 \bmod 8$, then $n^2 \equiv 1 \bmod 8 \equiv 1 \bmod 8$.

If $n \equiv 3 \bmod 8$, then $n^2 \equiv 9 \bmod 8 \equiv 1 \bmod 8$.

If $n \equiv 5 \bmod 8$, then $n^2 \equiv 25 \bmod 8 \equiv 1 \bmod 8$.

If $n \equiv 7 \bmod 8$, then $n^2 \equiv 49 \bmod 8 \equiv 1 \bmod 8$.